# How to auto press ok on javascript alert

Tags: javascript, html

I want to code the javascript alert so when a message is displayed, the `OK` button is automatically pressed.

HTML

```
<html>
   <script language=javascript>
    function rdir()
      {
      alert("Please wait while the page is redirected!");
      window.location="/alarms_act_lat.htm";
      }
    </script>
  <body onLoad=rdir()>
    <center>
       <h1>LATCHED ALARMS ARE CLEARED</h1>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best way to do that, if you control the creation of the alert, would be to show some other kind of alert that isn't actually an *alert()* alert. Get a jquery plugin that shows customizeable alert boxes, use that instead.

Comment: You will have to display your message in the document rather than use the native `alert()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible – at least, not without a browser extension. All JavaScript execution in the browser stops during `alert()`.

Comment: I have html page with iframe and i display content from another page like router and i want to made page to control this router from my page i want when display this which above code my page press ok automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that English might not be your first language, but that comment is utterly incomprehensible.